# Git flow branch validation regex must end with letter

Tags: regex, regex-negation, visual-studio-code, regex-group, git-flow

I'm writting a regex to validate branch names. Basically, a branch can start with either feature, hotfix or release followed by a slash. Afterwards must be some letters or numbers (at least one) and then a separator, either a slash, a dot or a line followed by some more letters or numbers and so on. However, the branch name cannot end with a separator.

This is what I came up with.

```
^(features?|releases?|hotfix(es)?)\/([a-z\d]+[-/_.]?)+[a-z\d]$
```

However, the branch name `release/0` does not match while it should. However, when I remvoe the last character set the branch `feature/name_` would match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example what is after the forward slash is 1 character and your pattern expects at least 2 characters due to the 2 character classes `[a-z\d]+`.

One option is to match the character class first and repeat 0+ times a separator followed by the character class.

```
 ^(features?|releases?|hotfix(es)?)\/[a-z\d]+([-/_.][a-z\d]+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(features?|releases?|hotfix(es)?)` Match any of the options
- `\/[a-z\d]+` Match forward slash and 1+ times what is listed in the character class
- `([-/_.][a-z\d]+)*` Repeat 0+ times a delimiter and 1+ times the char class
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tQYqp/1)

If you don't need the capturing groups `()` You could make them non capturing instead `(?:)`

Comment: This works! (the `?` after `[-/_.]` seems redundant though) but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by using non capturing groups instead?

Comment: That is correct if `[-/_.]` is not optional. I have updated the answer. If you are not using what is captured in the group in your code or tool for example using a backreference to what is captured you can make them non capturing. [This page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for example could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Would

```
^(feature(s)?|release(s)?|hotfix(es)?)(\/[a-z\d]+)([-/_.][a-z\d]+)+$
```

Be what you need?

Comment: Edited my answer to fit this

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the stuff after your first `/` is:

```
([a-z\d]+[-/_.]?)+[a-z\d]$
```

Which means "at least one alphanumeric followed by a separator" OR "at least one alphanumeric (no separator)" and then an alphanumeric. In other words, at least two characters total.

If you change that middle `+` to `*`, I think you'll get what you want:

```
([a-z\d]+[-/_.]?)*[a-z\d]$
```